# how to pass the result of SELECT statement to Stored Proc

Tags: sql

what's the proper way to write it?
Thx

```
  SELECT 
      [JobId] as jobid


  FROM [v_Jobs]
  WHERE jobreference =177127

EXEC    [dbo].[s_someStoredProc] @JobID = jobid
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Consider altering the proc so that it can be called using a @jobreference parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store that value in a variable:

```
DECLARE @MyJobID INT

SELECT 
      @MyJobID = [JobId]
FROM [v_Jobs]
WHERE jobreference =177127

EXEC  [dbo].[s_someStoredProc] @JobID = @MyJobID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MS SQL Server then you can do this very easily in Management studio. Rigth click on a stored procedure -> Execute -> Fill in the fields -> Management Studio generates a Query for you.

You can see how that works or just use the generated query.